# Failure in sqlite_session_driver active_tick: Error from SQLite database "lasso_session": 19 constraint failed

Tags: lasso-lang

I am having a recurring problem with Lasso 9.2.6 where the instance slows to a crawl performance-wise and throws these errors to the log:

> Failure in sqlite_session_driver active_tick: Error from SQLite
>   database "lasso_session": 19 constraint failed

Restarting the instance solves the performance problem temporarily, but errors continue to appear.

Any recommendations for cleaning this up or resetting the session database to clear out invalid data?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on traffic volume or logging volume you may be overloading the sqlite tables. It's hard to say exactly what the cause is without checking, but I'd look at the settings for sessions. Consider setting the sessions to use either memory or the MySQL driver (I recommend a Memory table if using MySQL).

Have a look at the size of the tables and check if any are excessively large. You can just run ls -l /var/lasso/instances/default/SQLiteDBs/ or use a sqlite tool. The logbook and email tables are also likely suspects.

Comment: lasso_logbook 1.6 GB(!), lasso_session 10 MB, lasso_email 9 MB. I've switched to MySQL sessions for the moment to see if the issue tracks with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: After running vacuum on the lasso_logbook table, it's down to just 3KB. The other tables shrunk by about 2 MB each.

Comment: Cleaning up the other tables was a good thing to do, but I do want to point out that the error was with the lasso_sessions file. I've seen this on sites with moderate traffic - usually our files were either corrupted or left lock. For sites with decent traffic, using MySQL or Postgres is the way to go.